# What are the possible 'Random Boss' encounters and is there a reliable way to trigger them?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Sometimes, you get a 'Random Boss Encounter'...  Theres a big HP bar on top of the screen, but you are in the middle of the open world.

What are the possibilities for these random boss encounters, and is there a reliable way to trigger them? If there isn't, what could be the factors that do spawn a boss? Is it just completely random?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're always in the same spot (and after a Blood Moon, they all respawn). You can see a full map of them [at IGN's Hyrule map](http://www.ign.com/maps/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/hyrule).

You can find a few types of bosses:

- Hinox: These are the one eyed giants. They primarily drop a handful of weapons.

  - Stalnox: These are like Hinox, but only available to fight at night. They're a bit different from Hinox as they throw bones at you frequently (making it harder to run away and fight them at the same time). You can stop them by shooting them in the eye.
- Talus: These are the rock type monsters. They drop lots of valuable gems.

  - Igneo Talus: Same as a Talus, but made of hot rock that must be cooled down with ice before climbing him. A full 2*+ Fireproof set also works because it negates burning.
  - Frost Talus: Ice counterpart to the Igneo Talus. The armor that helps here is the Rito set or Zant's Helmet.
  - Igneo Talus Titan: A very large Igneo Talus that's encountered during the Ballad of Champions. Too large to be climbed normally, but updrafts spawn around it.
- Molduga: 4 of these can be found in Gerudo Desert. They drop treasure chests and crafting materials.

  - Moldoqueen: Another Ballad of Champions enemy. Didn't notice any major difference to a normal Molduga, except for buffed health.

A worthwhile mention is Lynels. They don't get a health bar, but they're stronger than most bosses and drop some crafting materials for end-game stuff as well. They're also the only enemy that grows stronger as you defeat Titans, rather than through the standard difficulty scaling system (or not at all for bosses).

Comment: I also encountered a skelton-version of a Hinox (forgot his name, though). Drops and fight are about the same as a Hinox, but apparently only happens at night.

Comment: Yes, those are called Stalnox. I mentally just categorized them as Hinox but I'll note them since they do have some differences.

Comment: There's actually 4 Moldugas across Gerudo Desert. And if you mention Stalnoxes separately, you should also drop a word on the Elemental Taluses and the DLC variants (Moldoqueen and Giant Igneo Talus; if the answer has been written pre-DLC then I'd still recommend updating).

Comment: @EgorHans Feel free to make an edit; I have not played the game since around this comment, and definitely pre-DLC.

Comment: Done. I also formatted it such that it's clearer which bosses are subtypes of others, and added an extra bit on Lynels.